# Digital menu for a restaurant

Tags: open-source

TL;DR: I need a web application where I can create a menu (for a restaurant) that contains nutritional values

Hello. I'm looking for some solutions to digitize the menu of a restaurant. So far, everything I've found on the internet either from tutorials or ready-made [and ready to customize, as it would be ideal to find] apps on codecanyon lets you create your own menu, add as many products/ingredients/photos as you want, but the problem is that it doesn't calculate your calorie count, which is a very important thing. Allergens are optional, i.e. if I can find a platform to create a menu that in addition to calories also shows allergens, that would be a super nice bonus, but it's not necessary.

There should also be a QR generated for the menu, but that's not something the platform/app should necessarily generate, once the menu PDF is created, I could easily make a QR for it.

So, any solutions?